# Content-Security-Policy Frame Ancestors

Tags: nginx, header, content-security-policy

We are trying to embed an external widget from pledge.to on our website. We are using this directive code in NGINX:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' frame-ancestors 'self' 'pledge.to';" always;
```

but we are getting an error message in console:

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'default-src' contains 'frame-ancestors' as a source expression. Did you want to add it as a directive and forget a semicolon?
```

How come this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have two directives, default-src and frame-ancestors and they need to be separated by a semicolon like this:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self' 'pledge.to';" always;
```